# restore Win 11 boot block on an external drive

Tags: boot, windows-11

I've seen plenty of answers on how to restore a bootblock on the internal disk (e.g. create a recovery thumb drive, boot from that, etc).

But in my case I have the failing hard disk from machine A mounted externally on (fully functional) machine B.

How do I rebuild the bootblock in this case?